# How to use pycodestyle on python 3 code with unicode strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8, pycodestyle

I get an error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2264' in position 0: character maps to 
when the pycodestyle check_files hits this line:

```
worksheet1.write_formula('E' + str(i), '=IF(F' + str(i) + '>G' + str(i) + ',"↑",IF(F' + str(i) + '=G' + str(i) + ',"↔","↓"))', arrows_format)
```

How can I keep using the Unicode and use the pycodestyle checker?
(I'm assuming it's the arrow characters that cause the error)

This seems important:
To capture the pycodestyle output (print) I use :

```
sys.stdout = open(ReportPath, 'w')
```

and save the 'print' output to a file. I think this is important because the 'print()' that pycodestyle tries does not actually happen.

Comment: It sounds like printing is indeed the problem - you probably need to ensure the console can handle unicode - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console?answertab=votes#tab-top